# No webpage was found for the web address using RestEasy

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, url, resteasy

I am trying to create a sample REST service using RestEasy. Below is my Java class

```
@Path("/message")
public class MessageRestService {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response getMessage(@PathParam("param")String msg){
        String result = "Hello World "+msg;
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

My `web.xml` is like below

```xml
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- this need same with resteasy servlet url-pattern -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
        <param-value>/rest</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher
        </servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>
            index.html
        </welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

The RestEasy version I am using is 3.0.12. When I hit the URL like below

```
http://localhost:8080/RestPathAnnotationExample/rest/message/test
```

This `localhost` page can’t be found.

```
No webpage was found for the web address: http://localhost:8080/RestPathAnnotationExample/rest/message/test
```

I am deploying on Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0):

You specified both `resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix=/rest` and

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>resteasy-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

that will use mapping on the specified path. It should work unless you give a correct configuration. You can learn more about [installation and configuration](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.0.1.GA/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html).

> RESTeasy is configured by default to scan jars and classes within these directories for JAX-RS annotated classes and deploy and register them within the system.